# Определение пароля в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, пароль

Я давно установил `postgresql` и забыл выбранный пароль. Как его узнать (к серверу `192.168.143.92` (`localhost:5432`))?

Comment: Узнать -- вряд ли. Изменить -- дело другое.
http://www.foogazi.com/2008/03/23/quickzi-how-to-change-postgresql-root-password/

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй в командной строке ввести: **net user postgres postgres**

Пароль должен сброситься на дефолтный: **postgres**